# What's the point of upgrading this ability?

Tags: dungeon-boss

Is there any point in upgrading Heal Ally for [Sifu Jianzhi](http://dungeonboss.wikia.com/wiki/Sifu_Jianzhi)?

The amount it says it heals doesn't change from one level to the next...

[image]